# How can I delete the lines which include subStr1 and subStr2 in a big file?

Tags: perl, file-io

How can I delete the whole lines which included both `subStr1` and `subStr2` in a big file and save as a new smaller file.

Part of my file content below.

```
12-23 20:27:35:265   GetVariable [Tunnel]    INFO  iVid = 536876042 data [Reruen] = System.Object[]
12-23 20:27:35:265   GetVariable [Tunnel]    INFO  iVid = 536876043 data [Reruen] = System.Object[]
12-23 20:27:33:718   SendEvent [Link]    INFO  eventID = 268435564
12-23 20:27:33:718   WaferMove [Link]    INFO  waferNumber = 122253 UNIT_ID dest = UNIT_ID_LL_A  slot = 1 bool isStarted = False
12-23 20:27:35:265   GetVariable [Tunnel]    INFO  iVid = 536876042 data [Reruen] = System.Object[]
12-23 20:27:35:265   GetVariable [Tunnel]    INFO  iVid = 536876043 data [Reruen] = System.Object[]
12-23 20:27:33:765   WaferMove(d) [Link]    INFO  waferNumber = 122253 UNIT_ID dest = UNIT_ID_LL_A  slot = 1 bool isStarted = False
```

And I want to deleted all the lines include both `GetVariable [Tunnel]` and `System.Object[]`
like the lines below. THANKS.

```
12-23 20:27:35:265   GetVariable [Tunnel]    INFO  iVid = 536876043 data [Reruen] = System.Object[]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can afford to have a copy of the file (which is probably safer to do) then you can open two files (one for reading original file one for writing to the result file) and skip the lines where you find the match:

```
open(ORIG, '<', 'orig.txt');
open(RESULT, '>', 'result.txt');
while(my $line = <ORIG>) {
  # fine tune this
  next if $line =~ /GetVariable\s+\[Tunnel\].*System\.Object\[\]/;
  print RESULT $line;
}
close ORIG;
close RESULT;
```

I haven't tried the script, so make sure to test it on an example file first.

**Edit:** you need to tune the regex. play with it a little.

Comment: Your regex matches _either_ of GetVariable or System.Object, but what he wants to skip is lines containing _both_. IOW, please replace the pipe (|) with a .* in the regex.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Perl's -i switch](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-i*%5b_extension_%5d) for in-place editing:

```
$ perl -i.bak -ne 'print unless /GetVariable\s+\[Tunnel]/ &&
                                /System.Object\[]/' file.log
```

This will leave a backup of your original in `file.log.bak`, and the filtered version will be in `file.log`.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -ne 'm/\QGetVariable [Tunnel]\E.*?\QSystem.Object[]\E/ || print;' data.log > data.log.new
```

Then just rename `data.log.new` to `data.log`.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for this being a non-Perl answer, but I would just spontaneously use grep:

```
grep -v "GetVariable \[Tunnel\].*System\.Object\[\]" infile > outfile
```

This could be done using Perl like this:

```
perl -wne'print unless m/GetVariable \[Tunnel\].*System\.Object\[\]/' < infile > outfile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    next if (/GetVariable \[Tunnel\]/ && /System.Object\[\]/);
    print $_ ."\n";

}
```

on the command line

```
$ perl myscript.pl inputfile > newfile
```

the above works also for "System.Object[]" that comes before "GetVariable [Tunnel]" and it will not delete lines that only has one of those patterns on the line.

Or

```
perl -ne 'print if($_!~/GetVariable \[Tunnel\]/ && $_ !~ /System.Object\[\]/)' file
```

Comment: Hi Ghostdog74, Your script works well. But when I try to run the last line. My practice script like this `perl -ne 'print if($_!~/GetVariable \[Tunnel\]/ && $_ !~ /System.Object\[\]/)' input.txt > output.txt` and alert the error as *** Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1. ***. I don't know why (') (from the last line of your script above) changed to another character (') on my win command line? Thanks.

Comment: windows cmd.exe doesn't like single quote. So use double quote.

Answer (score 1):

See [perlfaq5](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq5.html)'s answer to [How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How_do_I_change_dele):

---

How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?

(contributed by brian d foy)

The basic idea of inserting, changing, or deleting a line from a text file involves reading and printing the file to the point you want to make the change, making the change, then reading and printing the rest of the file. Perl doesn't provide random access to lines (especially since the record input separator, $/, is mutable), although modules such as Tie::File can fake it.

A Perl program to do these tasks takes the basic form of opening a file, printing its lines, then closing the file:

```
open my $in,  '<',  $file      or die "Can't read old file: $!";
open my $out, '>', "$file.new" or die "Can't write new file: $!";

while( <$in> )
    {
    print $out $_;
    }
```

close $out;
Within that basic form, add the parts that you need to insert, change, or delete lines.

To prepend lines to the beginning, print those lines before you enter the loop that prints the existing lines.

```
open my $in,  '<',  $file      or die "Can't read old file: $!";
open my $out, '>', "$file.new" or die "Can't write new file: $!";

print $out "# Add this line to the top\n"; # <--- HERE'S THE MAGIC

while( <$in> )
    {
    print $out $_;
    }
```

close $out;
To change existing lines, insert the code to modify the lines inside the while loop. In this case, the code finds all lowercased versions of "perl" and uppercases them. The happens for every line, so be sure that you're supposed to do that on every line!

```
open my $in,  '<',  $file      or die "Can't read old file: $!";
open my $out, '>', "$file.new" or die "Can't write new file: $!";

print $out "# Add this line to the top\n";

while( <$in> )
    {
    s/\b(perl)\b/Perl/g;
    print $out $_;
    }
```

close $out;
To change only a particular line, the input line number, $., is useful. First read and print the lines up to the one you want to change. Next, read the single line you want to change, change it, and print it. After that, read the rest of the lines and print those:

```
while( <$in> )   # print the lines before the change
    {
    print $out $_;
    last if $. == 4; # line number before change
    }

my $line = <$in>;
$line =~ s/\b(perl)\b/Perl/g;
print $out $line;

while( <$in> )   # print the rest of the lines
    {
    print $out $_;
    }
```

To skip lines, use the looping controls. The next in this example skips comment lines, and the last stops all processing once it encounters either **END** or **DATA**.

```
while( <$in> )
    {
    next if /^\s+#/;             # skip comment lines
    last if /^__(END|DATA)__$/;  # stop at end of code marker
    print $out $_;
    }
```

Do the same sort of thing to delete a particular line by using next to skip the lines you don't want to show up in the output. This example skips every fifth line:

```
while( <$in> )
    {
    next unless $. % 5;
    print $out $_;
    }
```

If, for some odd reason, you really want to see the whole file at once rather than processing line-by-line, you can slurp it in (as long as you can fit the whole thing in memory!):

```
open my $in,  '<',  $file      or die "Can't read old file: $!"
open my $out, '>', "$file.new" or die "Can't write new file: $!";

my @lines = do { local $/; <$in> }; # slurp!

    # do your magic here

print $out @lines;
```

Modules such as File::Slurp and Tie::File can help with that too. If you can, however, avoid reading the entire file at once. Perl won't give that memory back to the operating system until the process finishes.

You can also use Perl one-liners to modify a file in-place. The following changes all 'Fred' to 'Barney' in inFile.txt, overwriting the file with the new contents. With the -p switch, Perl wraps a while loop around the code you specify with -e, and -i turns on in-place editing. The current line is in $*. With -p, Perl automatically prints the value of $* at the end of the loop. See perlrun for more details.

```
perl -pi -e 's/Fred/Barney/' inFile.txt
```

To make a backup of inFile.txt, give -i a file extension to add:

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/Fred/Barney/' inFile.txt
```

To change only the fifth line, you can add a test checking $., the input line number, then only perform the operation when the test passes:

```
perl -pi -e 's/Fred/Barney/ if $. == 5' inFile.txt
```

To add lines before a certain line, you can add a line (or lines!) before Perl prints $_:

```
perl -pi -e 'print "Put before third line\n" if $. == 3' inFile.txt
```

You can even add a line to the beginning of a file, since the current line prints at the end of the loop:

```
perl -pi -e 'print "Put before first line\n" if $. == 1' inFile.txt
```

To insert a line after one already in the file, use the -n switch. It's just like -p except that it doesn't print $_ at the end of the loop, so you have to do that yourself. In this case, print $_ first, then print the line that you want to add.

```
perl -ni -e 'print; print "Put after fifth line\n" if $. == 5' inFile.txt
```

To delete lines, only print the ones that you want.

```
perl -ni -e 'print unless /d/' inFile.txt

    ... or ...

perl -pi -e 'next unless /d/' inFile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the completed reference.